# Expanding the Recommendations Flag

Tags: feature-request

Recently, [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/299988/kerbal-space-program-is-there-a-way-to-create-new-planets) came up on Arqade, seemingly asking for mod recommendations for Kerbal Space Program. Regardless of what the question asks, there seems to be an unspoken rule/assumption that the "software" part of the recommendations flag covers mods.

Would it be a good idea to add mods to that shortlist of items in the recommendations flag? It may help clear up confusion in some places, as well as further expanding our ruleset. Personally, I never thought to include mods as part of the "software" rule; i assumed software would be things like cheat systems, map programs, and the like, not necessarily a recommendation of mods for Fallout 4 or the like.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, the flag text is:

> Questions that ask for recommendations of games, servers, software, or hardware are off topic. For more information on why these sorts of questions don't work here, see "So, what actually is a Game-Rec?" and "Q&A Is Hard. Let's Go Shopping!"

I assume that the OP suggests this (or similar, changes in bold):

> Questions that ask for recommendations of games, servers, **mods,** software, or hardware are off topic. For more information on why these sorts of questions don't work here, see "So, what actually is a Game-Rec?" and "Q&A Is Hard. Let's Go Shopping!"

I don't disagree with the suggestion because it would help new users.  However, it isn't a major problem to some because a mod is a form of software.  I don't think this change would have any real impact on the question highlighted.

In fact, I think this meta is more relevant to the original question that led to this meta:

[The community is closing "mod rec" questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8147/the-community-is-closing-mod-rec-questions)

Comment: Yep, this is what I was suggesting. More seasoned users like us might know that software includes mods, but for those who can only flag answers or who might have just reached the threshold for close vote powers, it could help in clarifying the rule set for the site.