# Questions about looking for mods for specific purposes

Tags: discussion

Recently, [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/266131/skyrim-looking-for-a-mod-that-stops-everyone-from-talking-to-you/266134) was put on hold as being about software recommendation, however I see other questions like [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65580/is-there-a-skyrim-mod-for-hiding-a-followers-helmet?rq=1), [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/98243/mod-to-disable-monster-level-scaling), and [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/143321/is-it-possible-to-remove-specific-quests-in-skyrim-with-mods), which seem similar to the question about turning off idle chatter, and none of them really look like "game recommendation" in the "Should I buy this game?" way, which is, from what I understood, against the rules for reasons similar to questions being too opinion based.

Then there's [this Meta question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5547/closed-mod-recommendation-skyrim-question-can-this-question-be-improved-and), which I think has a very relevant accepted answer. Did something change between that question being answered and now?

Comment: About the meta, it is from 2012. The 3 questions, they are from 2012 and 2013. A lot have changed since then, but they might still be on topic, but the asker IS providing what they want and ask us to find a mod that fits that criteria, hence I think that it should be off topic, just like game recommendations, as it is pretty much the same thing, but we are looking for different yet similar stuff (not like apples and oranges, but like HDDs and SSDs, the input (search process, the question) is pretty much the same, the output is different (the scale of supplied software, doesn't matter to us)).

Comment: Thanks for the list. I've voted to close those questions, too.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer As per [this highly voted answer](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/11579/4797), I've edited and voted to reopen the questions you mentioned in your post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The very relevant post you cite says:

> At worst, these are XY problems - the person has posted their problem and jumped to the assumption that the solution is modding the game.

The question was most likely closed because it assumed that the answer would be a mod, and then we just have to pick "the best" mod.

Don't ask us to pick a mod for you. Give us the actual problem — "how do I get people to stop talking to me?" — and we'll solve that, and if the solution involves a mod, so be it.

This is especially relevent in Skyrim as many solutions involve the developer console or mods, and you can't use those solutions on Playstation or XBox. Having a question about a mod or a console trick begs the very same question except *without* using a mod or a console trick...

Comment: Hm, it feels like a subtle difference to me and I'm not sure I really get it, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer maybe [this longer explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/13992) on the XY problem will help