# List of ______ blogs?

Tags: discussion, closing

Should [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25251/android-gaming-blogs) have been closed?

"List of `_________` blogs" are valid community-wiki questions on [every](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151974/c-blogs-that-you-regularly-follow) [other](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/game-development-blogs) [stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81/list-of-interesting-math-blogs)...

Comment: Many, many, many kinds of questions are disallowed here, but allowed on other SE sites. For example, we close down game-rec with a vengeance, but xxx-rec questions on other sites are usually allowed.

Comment: I would disagree with the latter half of @Arda's statement. N-rec questions are frequently found on new SE 2.0 sites, but less so on more mature ones (see: Cooking and Recipes).  Part of this arises out of the fact that the original Trilogy initially allowed these questions, but has become more staunch over time in their view of them.  That such questions linger on Trilogy sites, is often used as justification for emerging SE 2.0 sites, before they start to see the problems associated with this type of question.

Comment: They're not allowed on Android...

Comment: I saw this thread title on the feed and thought it was a spammer looking for porn sites... O_o

Answer (score 11):

This site does not operate any policy of "Allow X by making it Community Wiki" that you might find on other sites on the network. We find Community Wiki is best used as a tool for collaboration of easy editing, not as an enabler for classes of questions that would otherwise be off-topic. If a question is acceptable, it's generally appreciated that it should be acceptable without needing Community Wiki. That way, it is clearer that the material we accept is considered valuable and authoritative, as we reward it all. Also, Community Wiki only ever solved half the problems of list questions, anyway, but I digress as that's a tangent.

These are list questions that play out very similarly to shopping advice. Our normal response to such questions is "Teach people how to fish", to start over-using that proverb. We transform "What video game recording software is there?" into "How can I record videos of my gameplay?". Many of our fully prohibited and closed shopping advice questions occur because they cannot be suitably transformed into a practical problem that has conclusive answers. Thus if they are unable to find a comfortable fix, they remain in their itemized list state and are off-topic here.

[As it were, reading material is quite like gaming material - your non-list questions tend to end up still being templated shopping advice questions post-transformation](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/so-what-actually-is-a-game-rec/1841#1841).

Answer (score 8):

I don't think that is necessarily true; one question of that type may be *tolerated* but I'd say that's a far cry from being "valid". Per

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask-beta

> It’s tempting to start with easy, superficial questions: surveys, polls, and rudimentary questions like “what are some good books on this topic” or “what are the best blogs on this topic.” Those are not good questions for the private beta – they don’t reflect the actual content that we want this site to contain, and are not representative of it.

(this is a mandatory clickthrough page for every user's first question in a private beta as of a few months ago..)

Comment: That sounds like a good message to show on how-to-ask for all new users, not just on private beta sites.