# Just to clarify: are game-recommendations off topic on Arqade?

Tags: support, allowed-questions, game-recommendations

I tried to make sense of it and failed. I have questions about kind of games I like and would like to know games depending on different factors at time. I am lost because the question asked and the answer given doesn't really tell what the consensus was.

It does seem however that game-recommendations is no longer a tag. Am I correct in assuming that this means they're off-topic?

Comment: To add to the answers here, game recommendation is on topic at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 15):

Game recommendations are **off-topic** and there's a close option for off-topic -> game/software/hardware recommendations.

Comment: Upvoted because this answer puts effort into answering concisely.

Comment: Upvoted because OP has no delusions about the amount of effort he put into the answer.

Answer (score 10):

While game-recommendation is a tag that we apparently have (I looked), game recommendations themselves are not on-topic here.

From our list of close reasons: "Questions that ask for recommendations of games, software, or hardware are off topic. For more information on why these sorts of questions don't work here, see ["So, what actually is a Game-Rec?"](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/so-what-actually-is-a-game-rec) and ["Q&A Is Hard. Let's Go Shopping!"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)"

It basically comes down to the fact that stuff like this is really subjective and opinion based. There are a large number of people in this community, and let's say I want games that are like Ocarina of Time. If I ask that, I am going to get a whole lot of different games, and a whole lot of different reasons why someone thinks their suggestion is most like what I am looking for. It's really hard to judge that sort of thing, and we've found that stuff like that really just doesn't work here.

Comment: Also, voting becomes a popularity contest instead of an objective measure of the answers' worth.

Comment: Upvoted, because this answer actually shows signs of effort put into it.

Answer (score -5):

They are off-topic because answers on such questions are opinion based.