# Why is this question about "recommendations of games"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I've recently asked [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/343552/100233).

Currently it has 4 close votes that say

> Questions that ask for recommendations of games, servers, software, or hardware are off topic. For more information on why these sorts of questions don't work here, see "[So, what actually is a Game-Rec?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1617)" and "[Q&A Is Hard. Let's Go Shopping!](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping)"

I have read the linked pages and I cannot see how those apply to my question.

Could someone please clarify what makes my question a "shopping" one? I though I was asking for resources about a game.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question is a "recommendation" question because you're asking for us to find you an external resource based on the criteria you specify. Questions like this are technically off-topic, so they typically get closed.

However, I think you can still salvage the question by changing the wording to match the actual info you're looking for. Instead of asking where you can find a list of items, ask directly what items have been added since patch 3.0.0. It might sound like a pedantic difference, and in some ways it is, but it's important for the site to handle questions this way to avoid setting precedent for other, less-salvageable questions.

Comment: ok, I see the point. would have been nicer for some of the user to comment instead of only voting to close and wait for me to react. not sure it make sense to edit now, might be better to wait for it to get closed and then go for the reopen queue

Comment: The second paragraph continues to be my complaint with this closure logic. "What is this information" is not meaningfully different from "where can I find this information".

Comment: @Unionhawk It sounds pedantic, and then we get answers that are nothing more than links, which is the whole reason we close them in the first place

Comment: @Federico I actually was going to leave a comment explaining what Mage Xy did in their answer, but I did not.  Usually, questions asking to find a list of something are typically closed for the reason discussed.

Comment: @TimmyJim pardon the snark, but that's not really helpful

Comment: @Federico I agree with you, and for that I apologize.

Comment: @Frank It doesn't just sound pedantic it *is* pedantic. Reopen vote cast.

Comment: @Unionhawk And yet, the answer the question got read it *exactly* like the recommendation request it was.  It's just another reason why we shut these down until they're edited.

Comment: @Frank We do not close questions on the basis of their answers.

Comment: @Unionhawk No, we close them based on their topic space.  The answer just reinforces exactly why we close recommendations.

Comment: @Frank This is not a recommendation, it seeks information. Using the recommendation close reason here is confusing and, again, pedantic.

Comment: @Unionhawk And yet, I believe it was.  And the answer reinforces that interpretation.  Call it pedantic if you want, but I'm not seeing where it was the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @Frank "where can I find this info" is functionally the same as "what is this info". Either way, the question is edited, and I invite you to cast a reopen vote. What a productive use of everyone's time, forcing a question into the reopen queue because the wording is almost a recommendation if you squint hard enough at it.

Comment: @Unionhawk Gonna need to disagree on that one, but, sure, the edited question is much better.  Let's leave the snark at the door, too.