# Making a list to update a question's answers

Tags: discussion, lists

I've recently answered this question: [Do WALLS matter if I'm building the 6-inch brick defense from Corruption/Crimson for my city? [duplicate]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/150505/54659). The question was closed and points to a duplicate question aptly named [How does corruption spread?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/27258/54659).

Now, there are two problems that I see in this situation:

- First is that the 1st question shouldn't have been closed, IMO. The question asks for the effects of corruption spreading on background walls, which isn't covered in the duplicate question or in any of the answers given.
- Assuming the duplicate flag is well-intentioned (since the question is itself the highest-voted that relates to The Corruption), it's severely outdated. The answers refer to 2011, and the accepted answer relies a little on "guesswork", i.e.:

> [...] so I'm not sure who is correct.

The game has been recently updated, and since it's release, official and unofficial sources (the Terraria wiki at gamepedia and at the wikia pages) have confirmed some, if not all of the game's mechanics.

Now, my predicament is the following: I started to write an updated answer that encompasses everything that I can think it's worth to mention about Corruption spread. It's however a lengthy list, and most of it is copy-pasted from the sources. I am at the dilemma where just stating the links will incur in comments such as "*to prevent link-rot or to prevent users from looking at the page or etcetera*" and where posting the list (from what I was able to see on meta about the topic) has a dubious stance (check [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/624/re-evaluating-our-site-what-is-the-scope-of-an-acceptable-list-if-it-exists), [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3714/list-questions-for-the-old-republic-mmos-cw-closure-other) and also [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7558/what-list-questions-are-good)).

I ask for some guidance to this problem.

Comment: Outdated questions should be updated. Strap a bounty to it indicating such, comment on the particular answers, or even edit it yourself. I'm not gonna comment on the dupe closure, though, kind of busy right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I disagree in general with closing more specific questions as duplicates of a broad one if one can answer the broad one without answering the more specific question. Of course an ideal answer to the broad question would answer the specific one, but that is not always the case.

More specific questions are also not really harmful, even if they lead to a small amount of duplication. Sometimes you just want to know one small fact, and not having to search to an entire comprehensive answer for it can be useful. Those short specific questions are like bookmarks for a longer text.

As for your comprehensive answer, just post it. If you're worried about relying too much on links, quote short excerpts that contain the important information.

Comment: Related: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7359/3062